# Nivo Slider dose not load the Ajax response from PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, nivo-slider

I'm trying import images to HTML using PHP, but NivoSlider not loaded that.
I looked for the cause of the problem.
I am printing a alert message of *response* and the right.

Here is the HTML and AJAX query:

```
<div id="workcontent" class="pcontent" style="display:none;">
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var wl = $('#worklist div');
                wl.on('click', function(){
                    var name = $(this).attr('id');
                    console.log(name);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'read.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { data : name }
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        $('#slider').prepend(response);
                        alert(response);
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="back"></div>
    <div id="backcontainer">
        <div id="back">
            <a href="index.php">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div><!--End backcontainer-->
</div><!--End content-->
```

And here is the other jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider(function(){alert('OK');});
    });
</script>
```

This alert don't show! ):

Finally, here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["data"])){
    if ($_POST["data"] == "") {
            echo "data ures";
    } else {
        $data = $_POST["data"];
        $fname = "content/".$data."/*.*";
        $files = glob($fname);
        for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
        {
            $num = $files[$i];
            echo '<img src="'.$num.'" data-thumb="'.$num.'">';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "nem jott data";
}
?>
```

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NivoSlider doesn't take a function as an argument.**

Also `.nivoSlider()` is probably called **before** the AJAX call returns it's response.
A better solution would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'read.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data : name }
    }).done(function (response) {
        $('#slider').prepend(response).nivoSlider( {} );    
    });
});
```

Now you can be fairly sure `#slider` contains the images from the response body so NivoSlider can act on them.

Comment: Ohh, thx! I tried before the AJAX call, but I don't do it.
However your method it's succeeded!